# Change backboneJS webservice urls

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, restful-url

BackboneJS webservice default urls are in this format:

> /entities  GET fetch entities
>
> /entities/id   GET get entity

I have a RESTful webservice that expects url in this format:

> /entities?id=n

is there a simple way to force backbone to use this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your model, override the `urlRoot` property.

```
urlRoot: "/entities?id="
```

Alternatively, you can override `url` to take more control. (You will have to expand on this)

```
url: function() {
   return "/entities?id=" + this.id;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I already tried this, but it doesn't work. In this way, it generates an url like "/entities?id=/3", where "3" is the model id value.